# How is it Apple Watch works when the heart rate is 0?

Tags: apple-watch, watchos, health-kit

I am using Apple Watch series 2 to get heart rate information. It works very well but I have a question.

Is it possible to get a heart rate 0? I tried to get Apple Watch to measure things that have no heart rate, such as an umbrella and a racket. It showed 60 of 100 BPM even though these things definitely have no heart rate.

Does anyone know how it is that Apple Watch works when there is no heart rate? My Apple Watch has Watch OS 3.1.

Comment: It assumes that a dead person wouldn't be wearing a watch so it knows that a zero heart rate is irrelevant and discards the measurement, instead trying to compensate using historical data.